# btrfs fi du: several sets of shared extents

Tags: clone, btrfs, deduplication

I have a lot of files in various directories on a btrfs filesystem. They are all identical, and some may have been created using a "old-style" full copy, some are clones (`cp --reflink`). I want to find out whether there are any non-clones.

In some cases, there might be clones of old-style copies, see the `cp` example below. In such a case, the output of `btrfs fi du` is unhelpful: all the files have `0.00B` in the `Exclusive` column, and something in the `Set shared` column. But it's not necessarily *one* shared set. So I cannot use `btrfs fi du` to tell them apart. How can I?

---

I assume this is not detailed enough to be understood (but I wanted to put the question first), so here's a more elaborate example. Suppose I have two pairs of files; each pair's members are clones. In other words, I did this:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=a1 count=1 bs=1M
cp --reflink=always a1 a2
cp --reflink=never a1 b1
cp --reflink=always b1 b2
```

Of course, the files will take up 2MB on disk (each x2 shares its extents with x1).

I can see this using `btrfs fi du .` (last line)

```
     Total   Exclusive  Set shared  Filename
   1.00MiB       0.00B           -  ./a1
   1.00MiB       0.00B           -  ./b1
   1.00MiB       0.00B           -  ./a2
   1.00MiB       0.00B           -  ./b2
   4.00MiB       0.00B     2.00MiB  .
```

However, I cannot see it via `btrfs fi du *`:

```
     Total   Exclusive  Set shared  Filename
   1.00MiB       0.00B     1.00MiB  a1
   1.00MiB       0.00B     1.00MiB  a2
   1.00MiB       0.00B     1.00MiB  b1
   1.00MiB       0.00B     1.00MiB  b2
```

Here, I don't have the last line. I cannot distinguish this case (two pairs) from the case that all four files are in one single shared set (in other words, `cp a1 a2; cp a1 b1; cp a1 b2` all with `--reflink=always`); the output would be exactly the same.

Obviously, if all those files are in the same directory, I would just use `fi du .`. But if they are in different directories, I cannot do this. How can I get that "last line" that tells me if it's a single shared set or multiple separate ones?

Answer (score 2):

> Obviously, if all those files are in the same directory, I would just use `fi du .`. But if they are in different directories, I cannot do this. How can I get that "last line" that tells me if it's a single shared set or multiple separate ones?

Make it so they are in the same directory.

1. Create a temporary directory.
2. `ln` all the relevant files to the directory (i.e. create hardlinks). There may be name collisions, you may need to link some files to modified names.
3. Run `btrfs fi du .` in the directory.
4. Remove all the files inside the directory and the directory itself.

Comment: Thanks. I've thought of this, too, already (and it's a good trick that might help others having the same problem). However I'd prefer an easier solution, as I'm dealing with quite a lot of files and it's tedious to to all this linking...